# Angularjs: how to compare values from $scope using textbox

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm another newbie of `Angularjs.`
i want to know how can i compare the values from $scope.names using textbox
my `$scope.name` has a json encoded values. generated from content.php.

here is my code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
  <input type="text" ng-model="username">
</div>

<script> 
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("content.php")
.success(function (response)
   {
     $scope.names = response.records;
   });
});
</script>
```

if `$scope.names` has a array of object with `"username"`
like this.

```
{
  records:[{username:"john"},{username:"smith"},{username:"Metasploit"}]
}
```

how can i know if john exist using `textbox`..consider this as a simple login using Angularjs.
thank you, hope someone help me out.

Comment: what do you mean by compare ? did not get the question.

Comment: So you're trying to compare the username the user enters to what usernames already exist? A good place to start will be [Angular's Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: what i mean is that. if i input a string on a textbox.
 what will be the syntax for comparing/checking my input string to the $scope.names.

somesort of forEach loop of $scope.name 
then check if string from textbox exist.

Comment: Correct, you've practically answered it yourself. `angular.forEach()` can be used to loop through `$scope.names` and compare with `$scope.username`

Comment: thank you @Ankh . i thought there is another way around. it's working now.